# How to dynamically retrieve variables using strings

Tags: go

Such as:

```
type client struct{}
var s :="client"
var b := new (s)  //get a struct client
```

backgroud:
there are variables like `client_1`, `client_2`. now I try to check if client_x exists by request parameters:client(as string).

the result is:

- `client_1` exists
- `client_3` does not exists

And then I can retrieve variable `client_1` and use it.

Comment: Your background and title describe retrieving a *variable* by name, while your example code shows retrieving a *type* by name. Which one are you trying to do? In the first case, it's almost certainly an X Y problem. In the second case, it's most likely a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry I'm noob.I  want to check if the variable S(struct type) exists,if it does,I can use this variable.If it doesn't I'll do nothing.Because S implements Interface I( Has method M),If it exists.I can call S.M()

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a `map` of types, if that's what you're asking:

```
package something

// syntax error: unexpected type, expecting type
var types = make(map[string]type)
```

but you could do a map of `interface{}`, and just set each type to a default
value:

```
package main

var types = map[string]interface{}{"bool": false, "int": 0, "string": "hello"}

func main() {
   s := types["string"]
   t := s.(string)
   println(t == "hello")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At best, if you want to create a new type by name, you can put factory functions in a map.

```
type client struct{}
var types = map[string]func()interface{}{
    "client": func() interface{} { return new(client) },
}
```

The type `map[string]func()interface{}` is just "a map from strings to functions that take no arguments and return an `interface{}`".

You can then call the factory function by name:

```
func main() {
    s := "client"
    b := types[s]()
    _ = b
}
```

You can choose `interface{}` or a more specific interface for the return type of your functions, but the type must be the same for all functions in the map.

Comment: thanks,I edited the question.I don't want to declare a Map manually,If there is no other way.

Comment: @Josefa: You could run a program to automatically generate the map, by reading the Go source code.